# Dijit tab content rendering error

Tags: javascript, tabs, dojo, href, contentpane

I use dijit contentpane as tab. The tab content contain my custom widget. In the own widget I use dojo query for process the th elements, by my widget's id. If I set tab content by href: attribute, then works fine. But if I set tab content by content: attribute, then dojo query can not find the th elements. Would this be an rendering error? If I watch the my widget's containerNode, then I see the th elements. It seems dojo query can not find my widget's id. Interesting that my widget's other html elements rendered perfectly.

```
var tabContainer = registry.byId(data.parent);
var pane = new contentpane({ id:data.id, title:data.title, iconClass: 
data.icon, closable: data.closable, style: data.style});
if(data.content){pane.set('content', data.content);}                      
if(data.href){pane.set('href', data.href);}                  
tabContainer.addChild(pane);
tabContainer.selectChild(pane);
```

I check my widget's status by dojo.byId, and if I use the first (set content) method, my widget node is not registrated in the dojo.

Comment: Can you please include some code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You MUST call startup() method of Content Pane Dijit, see https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html

```
var pane = new contentpane({ id:data.id, title:data.title, iconClass: data.icon, closable: data.closable, style: data.style});
pane.startup();
```